# Objective C - HttpRequest with Daemon

Tags: objective-c, httprequest, daemon

i have created a daemon in Objective C that after search USB device, have to send an HttpRequest to an URL.

I have tried by Browser and the Host is reachable.

For create a Daemon i have used Foundation framework and with this, i have tried to create an HTTP request with this simply way:

```
NSURLRequest *eventRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_urlRequest cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20];

self.theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:eventRequest delegate:self];

if (self.theConnection) {
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"Connection Problem");
}
```

But in this case i have 2 problems:

1. The request was not send.
2. The Daemon ends and doesn't wait the response of HttpRequest.

How can i solve this problem?
Does exist another way to make an HTTP Request and get response?

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the normal way to send http message with the NSURLConnection Framework doesn't run the i have try the CoreFoundation.Framework to do that:

```
-(void)implementaZioneChiamata{

for (int i = 0; i < [_arrayOfSerial count]; i++) {

    CFStringRef urlFirst = CFSTR("http://192.168.30.9:88/virtualBadge.aspx?token=");
    CFStringRef token =(CFStringRef)_codicePWD;
    CFStringRef urlSecond = CFSTR("&serial=");
    CFStringRef serial = (CFStringRef) [_arrayOfSerial objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@%@%@%@", urlFirst,token,urlSecond,serial);

    CFStringRef strs[4];

    strs[0] = urlFirst;
    strs[1] = token;
    strs[2] = urlSecond;
    strs[3] = serial;

    CFArrayRef urlArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void*)strs, 4, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    CFStringRef urlCompleta = CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings(kCFAllocatorDefault, urlArray, CFSTR(""));
    NSLog(@"Url Completa: %@",urlCompleta);

    CFURLRef myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, urlCompleta, NULL);
    CFStringRef headerFieldName = CFSTR("host");
    CFStringRef headerFieldValue = CFSTR("192.168.30.9");


    CFStringRef requestMethod = CFSTR("GET");
    CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest =CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestMethod, myURL,
                               kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
      CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(myRequest, headerFieldName, headerFieldValue);
       CFDataRef mySerializedRequest = CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(myRequest);

    NSString *messReq = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData*)mySerializedRequest encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    CFStream


    NSLog(@"Serialized Request: %@", messReq);

}
```

in the first part of code i create the URL. After this i Inizialize the CFHTTPMessageRef for create the HttpRequest.But now there is the problem:

Once i have the HttpMessage to send it I need to Create the CFStreamRef for send the message. Starting to the idea that i create the stream how i can send message? With CFStream API?

ok Guy Tnx all for Help after open the stream the request was Send adding de stream like this.

```
CFReadStreamRef myReadStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, myRequest);

CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream);
```

Tnx all!!

Answer (score 0):

Many people find that the AFNetworking framework (GIT clone from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) makes HTTP interactions much easier.

Specifically, AFNetworking `getPath:` and `postPath:` methods accept a `path`, a `parameters` dictionary, and then two blocks, one for `success` and one for `failure`.  As such

```
{ [self getPath: @"users"
     parameters: @{ @"api_key" : @"AppAPIKeyForServer" }
        success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *json) {
          NSArray *users = json[@"users"];
          ....
        }
        failure: ...]; }
```

Creating AFNetworking clients is easy as well.  You can create a simple HTTP client or even for OAuth2 client:

```
@interface MyClient : AFOAuth2Client
@end

- (MyClient *) init
{
  if (self = [super initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: kMyClientAPIBaseURLString]
                           clientID: kMyClientOAuth2ClientId
                             secret: kMyClientOAuth2ClientSecret])
  {
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass: [AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader: @"Accept"
                     value: @"application/json"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

As for your daemon need.  You should be able to have your daemon retain a pointer to the AFNetworking client and then make repeated requests.

Note that an OAuth2 client is found at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NSURLConnection then send asynchronous request and use delegation,

```
// Create a Request and Connection
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection= [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
// Start Request
[theConnection start];
```

**Delegate Methods**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"did fail");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"did receive data");
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"did receive response ");
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"did finish loading");
    [connection release];
}
```